# How do I apply a logical operation between numpy arrays of different sizes?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an image stored as a numpy array with the shape (x,y,3). I have a mask that is a numpy ndarray of shape (x,y). How do I apply that mask to my image? `cv2.bitwise_and()` doesn't seem to work and neither does directly indexing with `image[mask]`. To be specific, my mask contains True and False and I want to perform `image & mask`, but applied to all layers at once instead of doing it one layer at a time (R,G,B) and combining them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `mask[:.:,None]`.  This makes `mask` out to be an array of dimension (x, y, 1), and the normal broadcasting rules can handle anding (x, y, 1) with (x, y, 3).

Comment: I'll add that an equivalent version would be `mask[...,None]`. The Ellipse operator takes the place of multiple `:`.